# $A$ and $B$ are closed subset of $\mathbb R$. Show that $A\cap B$ is also closed in $\mathbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Definition - A subset $S$ of $\mathbb R$ is said to be closed provided that if ${\{a_n}\}$ is a sequence in $S$ that converges to a number $a$, then the limit $a$ also belongs to $S$.

Actually, the exercise was two-part; first part was proof of the closedness of $A\cup B$ which is easy, but I can't prove for $A\cap B$.

- Suppose ${\{a_n}\}$ is a sequence in $A$. Its limit $a\in A$, so is $a\in A\cup B$; and if ${\{b_n}\}$ is a sequence in $B$ then its limit $b\in B$, so is $b\in A\cup B$. Q.E.D.

Would someone please guide me how to prove it only based on the mentioned definition.

Than kyou.

Comment: Regarding the union: What if $a_n$ is in $A$ for only certain terms (and in $B$ for the other terms)?

Comment: You know the union of any open sets is open? Using this fact is more efficient to see the desired result.

Comment: Your proof for the union is not correct. You need to work with sequences in $A\cup B$, not first a sequence in $A$ and then a sequence in $B$.

Comment: @David Mitra: I thought that after a while all numbers of sequence lie in some of them, but it's the case if it converges. You're right :)

Comment: @Chou: no intermediary theorem. I am trying to prove it based on the mentioned definition. :)

Comment: You need to take a sequence in **what you have to prove to be closed**. For example, take a sequence in $A\cap B$. Then it is a sequence in $A$ (conclusion) and it is also a sequence in $B$ (conclusion). Therefore (conclusion).

Comment: @A.G. - I got it! Thank you. However this method doesn't work for the case of $A\cup B$ (?)

Comment: If $(a_n)$ is a sequence in $A\cup B$, then infinitely many $a_n$ are in $A$ or infinitely many $a_n$ are in $B$.

Comment: @AlphaE For the union you have to extract subsequences. For example, if an infinite sequence belongs to $A\cup B$ then $A$ or $B$ must have an infinite subsequence. Continue working with it.

Comment: @DavidMitra / A.G. - $a_n$ is a sequence in $A\cup B$ and converges to point $a$; there are infinity many points of $a_n$ inside any arbitrary neighborhood of $a$; how do you prove that there **must** be some $N$ such that for $n\ge N$, all $a_n$ belongs to only one of $A$ and $B$? Or that mentioned neighborhood must be in one of the A or B? Not easy, I can't.

Comment: You cant. What if $A=B$? Argue like this: let $(a_n)$ be a sequence in $A\cup B$. Some subsequence  of $(a_n)$ is in $A$ or some subsequence is in $B$. Assume wlog that $(a_{n_k})_k$ is in $A$. If $(a_n)$ converges to $a$, then $(a_{n_k})_k$ converges to $a$ as well. Then, since $A$ is closed, $a\in A\subseteq A\cup B$.

Comment: @AlphaE It's not true that after some $N$ all further points must be either in $A$ or in $B$; consider $A=[0,1]$, $B=[1,2]$, and take the sequence $a_n=1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

For the intersection, you have to start with a (converging) sequence $\{a_n\} \subseteq A\cap B$, and you have to show that $\lim a_n \in A\cap B$.

Now, remember that by the definition of intersection we have both $\{a_n\} \subseteq A$ and $\{a_n\} \subseteq B$.

Can you take it from here?

For the union: let $\{a_n\} \subseteq A\cup B$. This sequence has infinitely many elements, some of the elements are in $A$ and some are in $B$. One of the sets must contain infinitely many elements from the sequence (why?), and let's assume (WLOG) that it's $A$.

So there are infinitely many indices $j$ for which $a_j \in A$. Thus we can construct a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ of $a_n$  that lies entirely in $A$. Now, since $a_n$ converges, so does its subsequence  $a_{n_k}$; and since $A$ is closed...

Comment: Would you please add the case of $A\cup B$? I explained in comments why I couldn't. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for $A\cap B$: let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence in $A\cap B$ with $a_n\rightarrow a~(n\to\infty)$. We need to show: $a\in A\cap B$.

We can definitely say that $a_n\in A$, so...can you take it from here?